# Haskell Type Misunderstanding assigning variables

Tags: haskell

Complete noob to haskell here, i'm trying to make this following piece of code work:

It's intent is to take the first exp elements of a list, concatenate them, then call the same function again.

```
order ( i ) (l1)(l2) =
        do exp <- (2 ^  i)
           l <- (take exp l1) ++ (take exp l2 ) ++ (order (i+1) (drop exp l1) (drop exp l2));
           return l
```

I'm sure this is far from idiomatic haskell, but you have to start some where though.

The error I am getting is on the

```
exp <- (2 ^ i )
```

saying that

```
No instance for (Num [Int])
      arising from a use of `^'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Int])
```

which i am really unsure what this exactly means. Isn't both 2 and i integers, and then applying the exponentiation function will result in an integer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've rewritten your code as follows and added a main.

```
order _ [] [] = []
order i l1 l2 =
                (take exp l1) ++ (take exp l2)
        ++      (order (i+1) (drop exp l1) (drop exp l2))
        where
        exp = 2^i

main = print $ order 1 [1,2,3,4] [3,4,5,6]
```

The first mistake you make is that your recursion doesn't terminate as `order` will always call itself again. The second mistake is in the use of `do`, this introduces a `monad` and considering you are new to Haskell, I would stay clear a bit. Use it only for I/O for now.

I hope this helps.

P.S: The error message you are getting is saying that a list of `Int` is used in a numeric way and there is no default implementation for that. This is probably caused by the `do` where the monad is over lists, but I'll leave it to cracks in Haskell to give an exact explanation.

Answer (score 3):

All statements in a `do` block must belong to the same monad. This includes the right hand side of `<-` bindings. Therefore, because the right hand side of the second statement `take exp l1 ++ ...` is a list, the compiler infers that the type of `2^i` must be a list as well.

This is because `<-` does more than just assign variables. In the case of the list monad, it sequentially binds the variable on the left to each element of the list on the right.

If you just want to bind a variable without any additional effects in a `do` block, you should use a `let` binding instead of `<-`.

```
do let exp = 2^i
   l   <- take exp l1 ++ ... 
   return l
```

That said, the use of `do` notation here is redundant. The monad laws guarantee that `do x <- m; return x` is the same as just `m`, so you can just write it directly as

```
order i l1 l2 = take exp l1 ++ ...
  where exp = 2^i
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bryan's points, I think I can help explain the reason you got that specific error.

The big reason is that `exp <- 2 ^ i` in a `do` block does **not** mean "let `exp` be a name for the value of `2 ^ i`" (You would express that meaning in a do block as `let exp = 2 ^ i`, but a `do` block isn't really what you want here anyway).

What `exp <- 2 ^ i` means is "let `exp` be a name for a value yielded by the monadic value `2 ^ i`". Try reading the `<-` as "comes from" rather than "is". What exactly "comes from" means depends on the monad involved. So for this line to mean something, `2 ^ i` must be a value in some kind of monad. Specifically, it's type is something like `Monad m => m a`, for unknown `m` and `a`.

Because the `^` operator works on numeric values, it returns something of type `Num a => a`. So that allows us to figure out that `2 ^ i` should be something of type `(Monad m, Num (m a)) => m a`, for unknown `m` and `a`.

`exp` is extracted from this mystery `m a`, so it is of type `a`. The next line includes expressions like `take exp l1`. `take` requires its first argument to be of type `Int`, and so `exp` must be of type `Int`, and so we can tell that that unknown `a` we were working with must be `Int`. So `2 ^ i` is now known to be of type `(Monad m, Num (m Int)) => m Int`; it is some sort of monadic integer.

In this line you also have `l <- (take exp l1) ++ ...`. So `l` also "comes from" some sort of monadic value. The right hand side can be seen to be some sort of list (due to the use of `++`, `take`, and `drop`). The monad involved in a `do` block must be the same throughout, and the list type constructor is indeed a monad. So if `(take exp l1) ++ ...` is a list of something, then `2 ^ i` must also be a list of something.

So now we have `2 ^ i` being of type `[Int]` (we originally knew it was `m a`; the `m` is the list type constructor `[]`, and the `a` is `Int`). But we also know (from the use of the `^` operator) that it must be a member of the `Num` type class. There is no instance of `Num` for `[Int]`, which is exactly the error you got.

That's just one of many inconsistencies that can be derived from the code you wrote; it's just the first one that GHC happened to encounter while trying to analyse it.